# nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even) with different align-items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox and I'm trying to have the nth-child(odd) to align-items:flex-start and nth-child(even) align-items:flex-end but all the children will align as the first child.How can I achieve this? Is there a way of doing that using flexbox and not float. My aim is for it to look a bit similar to facebook messenger.

```css
.received-message {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.received-message:nth-child(odd) {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.received-message:nth-child(even) {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.message-pop-up {
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}

.message-text {
  border: 2px solid #9c9696;
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

.message-pop-up:nth-child(odd) img {
  border-radius: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.message-pop-up:nth-child(even) img {
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="received-box">
  <div class="received-message">
    <div class="message-pop-up">
      <img src="https://cdn-fastly.hometalk.com/media/profile/2017/11/28/31906042_2.jpg?size=32x32" />
      <div class="message-text">
        <p>dsvdfvv</p>
        <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Offer, click here</a>
        <button>Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-pop-up">
      <img src="https://cdn-fastly.hometalk.com/media/profile/2017/11/28/31906042_2.jpg?size=32x32" />
      <div class="message-text">
        <p>dsvdfvv</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-pop-up">
      <img src="https://cdn-fastly.hometalk.com/media/profile/2017/11/28/31906042_2.jpg?size=32x32" />
      <div class="message-text">
        <p>Hello testing testing</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is exactly the question or the problem you are facing?

Comment: Edited the post for clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`align-items` will only work for flex containers. You need `align-self` for child elements of `flex` and it should be given to `message-pop-up` class not `received-message`.

For more info on `Flexbox`: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.received-message {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message-pop-up:nth-child(odd) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.message-pop-up:nth-child(even) {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.message-pop-up {
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}

.message-text {
  border: 2px solid #9c9696;
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

.message-pop-up:nth-child(odd) img {
  border-radius: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.message-pop-up:nth-child(even) img {
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="received-box">
  <div class="received-message">
    <div class="message-pop-up">
      <img src="https://cdn-fastly.hometalk.com/media/profile/2017/11/28/31906042_2.jpg?size=32x32" />
      <div class="message-text">
        <p>dsvdfvv</p>
        <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Offer, click here</a>
        <button>Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-pop-up">
      <img src="https://cdn-fastly.hometalk.com/media/profile/2017/11/28/31906042_2.jpg?size=32x32" />
      <div class="message-text">
        <p>dsvdfvv</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-pop-up">
      <img src="https://cdn-fastly.hometalk.com/media/profile/2017/11/28/31906042_2.jpg?size=32x32" />
      <div class="message-text">
        <p>Hello testing testing</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I will mark this as answer when it lets me.

Comment: @Naomi Glad to hear that it helps :) Happy coding.

Comment: Good solution, I think `.message-pop-up:nth-child(odd) { … }` is superfluous.